# Normalization on datasets with different distribution

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization, natural-language, tf-idf

I am having two datasets one is used for training a model and another one for testing it. The training dataset is large scale corpus of general context (parallel text) while the testing dataset contains text from specific domains. In the training phase tf-idf normalization is performed in the train dataset and the computed idf is used in the testing dataset to perform tf-idf normalization. However, the distribution of the vocabulary terms in the train dataset is much different than that of the testing dataset which as far as I understand deteriorates the classification results. Could you please, give any suggestions how to adjust the tf-idf normalization in this case? Also, if this is not a correct normalization approach could you please suggest a more suitable one? Thanks in advance.

<sup>**PS**: tf-idf is performed using sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer. Thus, in training and test phase fit_transform and transform are applied, respectively.</sup>

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that using the TF-IDF scores from completely different domain would be useful at all for the new task?

Comment: @Tim thanks for the response. The reason I have followed this approach is because the normalized train data are passed from a dimensionality reduction step. Thus, normalizing test data independently and then using the transformation matrix learned from the general data does not seems to me absolutely correct. Re-fiting the vectorizer in the domain specific data improves accuracy but based on the aforementioned rationale, I think that this it is not absolutely correct.

Comment: I was thinking how we can use the idf information from the general data to adjust the idf information of the vectorizer that is fitted in the domain specific data. For example to use the number of times a vocab term appears in the general data to normalize somehow the number of times a vocab term appears in the domain specific data   but I am not sure about that. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm asking because TF-IDF is completely dependent on the distribution of the data. "Adjusting" it to new distribution would basically mean calculating it from the scratch, so you would not be able to transfer what you've learned from the training set.